# Git pull via PHP shell_exec( ) works from SSH shell but not from web-browser

Tags: php, linux, git, web-hosting

I have a PHP script which is simply:

```
$output = shell_exec('git pull https://****@bitbucket.org/****/****.git 2>&1');
print_r($output)
```

I can SSH into my host and run this with "PHP scriptname.php" and it works fine and tells me everything is up to date within a fraction of a second.

However, when I try and run this same PHP script via the web-browser it hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Check the output of the .sh file with `/usr/bin/php -c "path/to/file.sh" to see if it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your webserver and ssh shell have different set of environment variables. In this case the trouble is `git` is missing in webserver's `$PATH` variable.

To fix it you can add directory with `git` binary to the `$PATH` variable

```
set PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin
```

or just call it by the full path
`/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin/git`

As for git credentials - try to find responsible env variable.

Comment: If I remove the change directory part and leave the git pull, the web browser still hangs and doesn't do anything. If it's not in the correct directory, it should return the error "fatal: not a git repostiory" error, but it just hangs. Note, it works when I am in terminal and run the php file using: php "script.php" but when I run the script from the browser it just hangs... I've edited my question to remove the change directory since it seems that it's not necessary

Comment: sorry I didn't check your edit. If you have enough rights try to issue `sudo -u www-data git pull <...>` to check the output. It is possible that your webserver user doesn't have write access to the target directory.

Comment: My hosting is on Godaddy and it doesn't have the sudo command, but I've checked and the SSH user and the PHP user are the same... I checked this with exec('whoami') in PHP. So my php script is running under the "myusername" user which is the same as the SSH user, so it should have the same privileges and access level as when I run it through terminal right?

Comment: It should, but your shell and webserver have different environment variable set. 
Try to run this `php -r "system('git pull <...>');"` in your ssh shell. Is it working correctly?

Comment: php "my_git_script.php" also works fine from the ssh terminal, just not from the web browser

Comment: I'm discouraged a bit :) May be environment variables comparing will give you a hint? Try to compare `env` command results from the shell and webserver execution.

Comment: Ok I made a script which just does shell_exec('env') and prints the result.... when I do env or php env_script.php from the SSH terminal, the results are quite similar.... but if I run that env_php.php in the webbrowser, the output looks very different, there's barely any info when running from the web-browser

Comment: Not sure exactly which variables, so I pasted most of the output on this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/GjF9iqF1

Comment: As you see the PATH variable differs drastically. Please check the "git" binary location by `which git`.

As a dirty fix try to add this line to the top of your bash script:
`set PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/REPLACEDUSERNAME/.local/bin:/home/REPLACEDUSERNAME/bin`

Comment: Thanks, I added '/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin/git' into the shell_exec and it now doesn't hang the browser which is great. I'm now getting the error "fatal: unable to set up default path; use --file fatal: could not read Password for 'https://*****@bitbucket.org': No such device or address" .... but at least it's not hanging so progress being made. My credentials were stored using git's credential manager so I guess there might be an issue with that from the browser or something, not sure

Comment: If you change your answer to having include the full git path (which I found by which git), I can accept that as the answer